# What is "range" actually? Is it a function?

Tags: go

One of the preferred way to loop through arrays and slices is to use `range` like this

```golang
arr = []int{1, 2}

for index, item := range arr {
  continue
}
```

I know how `range` works, I've been using it multiple times. But I'm still not sure what it is behind the scene. Is it a function and a modification of `range(arr)`? The fact that it returns 2 variables make me think that way, but I need a confirmation.

What's the implementation behind it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Range is one of the [keywords](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Keywords) according to the [spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec).

> ```
> The following keywords are reserved and may not be used as identifiers.
>
> break        default      func         interface    select
> case         defer        go           map          struct
> chan         else         goto         package      switch
> const        fallthrough  if           range        type
> continue     for          import       return       var
> ```

[For statements with range clause](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range)

> A "for" statement with a "range" clause iterates through all entries of an array, slice, string or map, or values received on a channel. For each entry it assigns iteration values to corresponding iteration variables if present and then executes the block.
>
> ```
> RangeClause = [ ExpressionList "=" | IdentifierList ":=" ] "range" Expression .
> ```

Answer (score 3):

A `for` with a `range` clause iterates over arrays, slices, map, strings and values received on a channel. The `range` [keyword](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Keywords) is syntax used by the compiler to distinguish this type of iteration from other iteration in a `for` statement.

The compiler implements `for` with a `range` clause.  The specification describes [for with a range clause](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range) in detail.

Answer (score 0):

It's an iterator-pattern which the for-loop uses to get the next object from.